# Bootstrap prevent overflow in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a simple navbar using Bootstrap, but when the screen size reduces the header spans over 2 - 3 rows and starts shadowing the form. Is there anyway to restrict the header to just one line?

https://jsfiddle.net/jaiasher88/8879m9yc/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <a href = "page-list.html" class = "navbar-text pull-left no-left-margin">
            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left glyphiconBackProperties default-blue"/>
        </a>
        <a class = "navbar-brand default-blue" href = "#">
            Edit Page
        </a>
        <a href = "page-list.html" class = "navbar-text pull-right">
            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphiconPlusProperties default-blue"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try using bootstrap rows and columns inside your container rather than just a plain container.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Using column works, but is there no easier way to do this?